# how to manually show comments and ratings WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on WooCommerce product now the client has a requirement to add reviews and ratings for every individual product now the theme I am using does not have the functionality of displaying reviews and ratings I verified it using the following code in case some else needs to know how to check whether reviews and ratings is enabled or not through code!

```
global $product;
if ( ! comments_open() ) {
    echo "false";
}
else
{
echo "true";
}
```

so it indeed displays true which confirmed my theme is not displaying the reviews and comments, so I did some searching and found a snippet to show reviews and ratings on product page which I used in file `theme/content-single-product.php` here is the code

```
<?php
/**
 * Display single product reviews (comments)
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.2.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
global $product;
if ( ! comments_open() ) {
    return;
}
?>
<div id="reviews" class="woocommerce-Reviews">
    <div id="comments">
        <h2 class="woocommerce-Reviews-title"><?php
            if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' && ( $count = $product->get_review_count() ) ) {
                /* translators: 1: reviews count 2: product name */
                printf( esc_html( _n( '%1$s review for %2$s', '%1$s reviews for %2$s', $count, 'woocommerce' ) ), esc_html( $count ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
            } else {
                _e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
            }
        ?></h2>

        <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

            <ol class="commentlist">
                <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) ); ?>
            </ol>

            <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
                echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
                paginate_comments_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args', array(
                    'prev_text' => '&larr;',
                    'next_text' => '&rarr;',
                    'type'      => 'list',
                ) ) );
                echo '</nav>';
            endif; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-noreviews"><?php _e( 'There are no reviews yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_review_rating_verification_required' ) === 'no' || wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) : ?>

        <div id="review_form_wrapper">
            <div id="review_form">
                <?php
                    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
                    $comment_form = array(
                        'title_reply'          => have_comments() ? __( 'Add a review', 'woocommerce' ) : sprintf( __( 'Be the first to review &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'woocommerce' ), get_the_title() ),
                        'title_reply_to'       => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'title_reply_before'   => '<span id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">',
                        'title_reply_after'    => '</span>',
                        'comment_notes_after'  => '',
                        'fields'               => array(
                            'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . esc_html__( 'Name', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
                                        '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" aria-required="true" required /></p>',
                            'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . esc_html__( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
                                        '<input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" aria-required="true" required /></p>',
                        ),
                        'label_submit'  => __( 'Submit', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'logged_in_as'  => '',
                        'comment_field' => '',
                    );
                    if ( $account_page_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) {
                        $comment_form['must_log_in'] = '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a review.', 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( $account_page_url ) ) . '</p>';
                    }
                    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' ) {
                        $comment_form['comment_field'] = '<div class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">' . esc_html__( 'Your rating', 'woocommerce' ) . '</label><select name="rating" id="rating" aria-required="true" required>
                            <option value="">' . esc_html__( 'Rate&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="5">' . esc_html__( 'Perfect', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="4">' . esc_html__( 'Good', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="3">' . esc_html__( 'Average', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="2">' . esc_html__( 'Not that bad', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="1">' . esc_html__( 'Very poor', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        </select></div>';
                    }
                    $comment_form['comment_field'] .= '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . esc_html__( 'Your review', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true" required></textarea></p>';
                    comment_form( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', $comment_form ) );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-verification-required"><?php _e( 'Only logged in customers who have purchased this product may leave a review.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Code taken from [wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments)

Now this code is working flawless I have no issue with the code but there is still one thing missing! I can add the review and ratings, it adds them to the db just fine and when I reload it shows me the count of reviews which means this part is working fine, I just need to display the comments as well underneath the review and comment section.

here is [the live link](http://clients.nextcrawl.ca/occ/ecommerce/product/muro128-ointment/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it myself anyone looking for this sort of issue should view the code below

```
 $args = array(
                'number'      => 100, 
                'status'      => 'approve', 
                'post_status' => 'publish', 
                'post_type'   => 'product' 
        );

 $comments = get_comments( $args );
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($comments);
```